# VFY: unable to resolve [many things]

Tags: android

I've a problem with VFY that tells me "VFY: unable to resolve virtual method" in the debugger but I don't really know how to solve it on Android Studio. Most of the time I can see people proposing many solutions on Eclipse but nothing on Android Studio.

The problem appears when I run my project on the API 19 or when I plug my smartphone to the computer. So I don't think that it is related to my code. It works when I run it on API 20 and more.

I use Android Studio 2.1.2.

If anyone could help me, thanks :)

Comment: There is nothing to solve. This is perfectly normal behavior, when code has references to newer classes/methods/fields/etc. that do not exist on the older device.

Comment: Alright. my targetSdkVersion is 23, do you think it is related to this value? Do you think I need to downgrade this value?

Comment: "do you think it is related to this value?" -- no. "Do you think I need to downgrade this value?" -- no. What you need to do is ignore those lines, unless you have **specific evidence of an actual problem**, such as your app crashing. Then, those lines might be helpful in understanding the Java stack trace associated with the crash. `VFY` lines themselves are not indicative of a problem.